Web scraping with selenium issues not finding an element
I am trying to webscrape using selenium on Google Colab, but I am running into an issue when trying to find an element, particularly a link, after copying its xpath.
Website I want to scrape
First part of my code
Second part of my code
Third part of my code
I have tried staggering wait times, and copying full XPATH instead of just XPATH. I also tried doing the same steps I used to try to scrape this link with another website and it worked. This lead me to believe that there was an issue with the specific website I was trying to scrape initially. Earlier on, I ran into an issue using beautiful soup where it would say my access was denied, so maybe the reason I'm getting errors is because it is blocked this way too, although that isn't as apparent as before when I used Beautiful Soup. Anyways, I attached a picture of my entire code (in addition to the specific code I am talking about below), as well as a screenshot of the website with the thing I want to scrape when I inspect it. Please let me know if you have any ideas to work around this issue or if I am just simply doing something wrong.
This is my code:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')

And this is the error I get:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-acdf74b871c1> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 driver.get(url)
      3 
----> 4 link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    227                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=126.0.6478.63); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56f9edf3869a <unknown>
#1 0x56f9edc1b0dc <unknown>
#2 0x56f9edc67931 <unknown>
#3 0x56f9edc67a21 <unknown>
#4 0x56f9edcac234 <unknown>
#5 0x56f9edc8a89d <unknown>
#6 0x56f9edca95c3 <unknown>
#7 0x56f9edc8a613 <unknown>
#8 0x56f9edc5a4f7 <unknown>
#9 0x56f9edc5ae4e <unknown>
#10 0x56f9edefe86b <unknown>
#11 0x56f9edf02911 <unknown>
#12 0x56f9edeea35e <unknown>
#13 0x56f9edf03472 <unknown>
#14 0x56f9edececbf <unknown>
#15 0x56f9edf28098 <unknown>
#16 0x56f9edf28270 <unknown>
#17 0x56f9edf377cc <unknown>
#18 0x7c8a0be61ac3 <unknown>


Can't see enough of the markup to know why the locator is bad there...but you're currently trying to target a , not the <a href... in there.  Your 2nd screenshot shows that they've identified you as a bot, and are suggesting you use their API with a link to: https://www.sec.gov/developer  Using their API will be much easier.

This appears to extract the content you're looking for:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

URL = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1346824/000110465924035606/0001104659-24-035606-index.html"

DRIVER_PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

service = Service(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(URL)

link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')

print(link)
print(link.text)

driver.close()

Output:
tm249128d1_sc13da.htm

I would advise against using the --headless flag when launching the browser. It seems that headless activity is being flagged (see screenshot below).


I am getting an error: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/126.0.6478.126/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
What program are you using to run this code? I just copied your code straight up. I am using google colab so I have to install all these things and it might be causing the difference in the way our programs run.

I've updated my answer. I'm not sure whether you can run Selenium without --headless in Colab. I suggest running it locally.
